# Sending a job to spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, cassandra

I have setup a spark cluster using cassandra as data cluster in stand alone mode. On the other hand I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to write the driver code to be sent to the spark cluster to be executed by the workers.

What I would like to know if it is possible to execute code from intellij (in my local machine) into the remote cluster or I must create a .jar file and deploy it to the workers with the sopark-submit?.

I'm just looking for a confirmation because I'm having problems doing all setup and need to reduce possibilities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible or at least I've never seen someone who succeeded (I've tried with Yarn without success)

Comment: I see this is a bit of a pain then to do. I wanted to use spark to generate reports from cassandra to feed an Neuronal network. I need this to be fastin execution and usability. If I have to always create a jar with the code for the report, upload to the master server, run spark-submit and retrieve the result for example from a created csv or whatever spark looses a lot of its charm. Can you confirm this is the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must execute code on `Spark-cluster` and set up configuration of this cluster to your `SparkContext` thereby you can write code in Intellij and deploy your code to remote cluster where Spark will execute it, I recommend you to read [spec](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) about submitting an application on the cluster.
Configuration for launching app can be next:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://${yourip}:7077 \
  --executor-memory 5G \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

If you wouldn't like to rconnect to cluster directly, you can make `jar` file and deploy it on cluster without connection via `spark-submit` - this [video-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BeTWT8ADfE) shows how to make it.
HTH

Comment: So, after configuring spark master and 2 nodes correctly (I can see them in the web frontend it provides), I MUST always do a spark submit?. I don't understand what you mean by "thereby you can write code in intellij and deplot your code to remote cluster". Does this mean I always have to create a jar from intellij and upload it to the server and do the spark-submit thing? I can't just write code locally and execute directly from the ide against the cluster (By pressing Run) like in any other language? THanks in advance.

Comment: @Notbad If you want to run your code on spark-cluster and launch anything from IDE you must set up the configuration of your cluster in your SparkConf - of course, it can be a cluster on the remote machine you just need to specify ip address.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to Debug the Driver program using IntelliJ.

You could 'spakr-submit' the application in Client mode and then use the IntelliJ IDE to attach to the driver.